# T-SQL query to replace special characters with a specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query:

```
select p9.[Name]
from [CleanGuestNames] p outer apply
     (select replace(p.[Name], '@', '*') as [Name]) p1 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '&', '*') as [Name]) p2 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '\', '*') as [Name]) p3 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '?', '*') as [Name]) p4 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '/', '*') as [Name]) p5 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], ':', '*') as [Name]) p6 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], ';', '*') as [Name]) p7 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '.', '*') as [Name]) p8 outer apply
     (select replace(p2.[Name], ',', '*') as [Name]) p9 ;
```

Codes above are supposed to replace all characters mentioned therein with a * in the [Name] column.

When I run the query, I still get records as follows from the [Name] column:

```
Alex / Sandrine SINNOF / VAN ACK
Peter / Jane KELLY
```

Expected Results:

```
Alex * Sandrine SINNOF * VAN ACK
Peter * Jane KELLY
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you keep replacing on `p1.[Name]`, not `p1.[Name]`, then `p2.[Name]`, then `p3.[Name]`. Though, personally, I would suggest just nesting the `REPLACE` functions. If you were on a fully supported version of SQL Server, then `TRANSLATE` would be a much better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is really a typographical error, as you are consistently referencing `p1.[name]` and so you are, in the end, only removing the characters `@`, `&`, and `,`. You need to be refereing `p2.[name]`, `p3.[name]`, etc:

```sql
select p9.[Name]
from dbo.[CleanGuestNames] p outer apply
     (select replace(p.[Name], '@', '*') as [Name]) p1 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.[Name], '&', '*') as [Name]) p2 outer apply
     (select replace(p2.[Name], '\', '*') as [Name]) p3 outer apply
     (select replace(p3.[Name], '?', '*') as [Name]) p4 outer apply
     (select replace(p4.[Name], '/', '*') as [Name]) p5 outer apply
     (select replace(p5.[Name], ':', '*') as [Name]) p6 outer apply
     (select replace(p6.[Name], ';', '*') as [Name]) p7 outer apply
     (select replace(p7.[Name], '.', '*') as [Name]) p8 outer apply
     (select replace(p8.[Name], ',', '*') as [Name]) p9;
```

Personally, however, I would suggest nesting all the `REPLACE` functions:

```sql
SELECT R.[Name]
FROM dbo.CleanGuestNames CGN
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(p.[name],'@',''),'&',''),'\',''),'?',''),'/',''),':',''),';',''),'.',''),',','')))R([Name]);
```

If you were on a supported version of SQL Server, you could make it much more succinct with `TRANSLATE`:

```sql
SELECT T.[Name]
FROM dbo.CleanGuestNames CGN
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(p.[name],'@&\?.:;.',',,,,,,,,'),',','')))T([Name]);
```